# How to automatically and securely deploy new mySQL instance with docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, deployment

I would like to be able to run a script that deploys my application to a new server with as few manual steps as possible, without exposing the database password to the world.

The application consists of a web application (nginx + custom stuff) and a mysql database. I know how to deploy it automatically, but not securely: just store the root password in docker-compose and somewhere in web app configs. This, obviously, is not secure at all.

I know how to deploy it securely: current [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html) suggests to deploy default mySQL image, grep the generated root password, then run mysql within the container to change this password to "the password of your choice". Then, I suppose I would have to put this "password of my choice" in the web application config, so my web application is able to connect to the database.

What I don't know is what is the recommended way to deploy mySQL both automatically AND securely. I can generate the "password of my choice" during the deployment, but if I am putting it in the configs anyway, what's the point of bothering with mySQL one-time randomly generated password? Can someone please point me to the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the official guidance for [environment variables on compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

You want your `docker-compose.yml` committed to source control, so the passwords should not be in there.  According to the official [mysql docs on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) the main variable you need to provide is `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

In fact their example provides this to the `docker run` command with the `-e` flag:

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

That can end up in logs, so instead I put this in a file `.env` with other config variables in the root of my project.

```
# .env
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
```

Then in the compose file reference this `.env` file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
```

You can also add the line `.env` to your `.gitignore` file within the project, so that secrets are not accidentally commited.

Then deploy a `.env` file by another means to each environment.  Of course be sure to `chmod 600 .env`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What "other means" do you suggest for creating the  .env file? Generate locally as part of init? Or copying over ssh? Also, if I remember correctly, .env file is always taken from the current directory, which complicates things and may cause weird failures, but I guess this is not a show stopper.

Comment: The next step might be to investigate swarm secrets.  [This thread](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5077/docker-security-risks-passing-secrets-over-environment-variables) has some good info, with a comparison to this method.

Comment: v25, very helpful, thank you very much for the insight!